# Adding And Reading cookies

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies

I want to set cookie in my response at login time, and what to read that at each request after that.
For this I have added cookie like this at the login time:

```
Cookie cookieClientId = new Cookie("id", token.getTkn());
    cookieClientId.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
    response.addCookie(cookieClientId);
```

When request come i check for th cookie present or not like this :

```
cookies = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getCookies();
  cookieId = null;
  if (cookies != null) {
              for (Cookie ck : cookies) {
                System.out.println("ck--------------- "+ck.getName());
                   if (ck.getName().toString().equals("id")) {
                           System.out.println("id cookie equal");
                           cookieId = ck.getValue();
                           System.out.println("cookie id " + cookieId);
                          System.out.println(cookieId.equals(authToken));
                            if (cookieId.equals(authToken)) {
                                isSecretAndKeyValid = true;
                            }
                        };
                    }
```

But the problem I am facing is i get the cookie only in the first request in after lo-gin request. and after that in each request i don't fine any cookie with that name'id' ,which i have set at lo-gin request time.

I tried to search for cookie adding ,retrieving method ,i found this only at almost everyplace.

Comment: when r u setting cookie . Is it before or after login  ?

Comment: at authenticate method after authentication.

Comment: Did you checked if the cookie is set in the browser (dev tools)? Where do you call your code to search for the cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you send a cookie to the browser,the browser will return the cookie to all servlets and JSPs within the directory that sent the cookie and all subdirectories of that directory. To make cookie available to the entire application, you can set the path to "/". (Quoted from Murach's Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition)

```
Cookie cookieClientId = new Cookie("id", token.getTkn());
cookieClientId.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
cookieClientId.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookieClientId);
```

Comment: yes. and it's quite unfortunate that the path is not set to `"/"` *by default*

Answer (score 0):

for each http request, the cookie is isolate, you have to store cookie data on your client side, then at each request, you set the cookie in like this:

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {

        cookieString += cookie.toString();          
    }

    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookieString);
```